# Написать программу для работы со списками

Tags: python, python-3.x

Элементы списка вводить с помощью генератора случайный чисел.В одномерном списке A=(a1, а2, ..., аn) группу, содержащую наибольшее число подряд идущих положительных элементов, переписать в хвост списка

```
        y =[] 
x = 0 
q =[] 
q1=[]
import random 
for i in range (15):
    y.append (random.randint (-20, 50)) 
print (y) 
while x < len(y) and y[x]>0:
    q.append(int(y[x]))
    x +=1
    z=len(q)
    print(z)
print(q)
```

Я сделал генератор для заполнения списка и заполнение списка положительными элементами, когда все положительные списки будут готовы, я хочу просто сравнить их по длине и наибольший переместить в хвост. Но как начать проверять по индексу элемент после первого отрицательного числа, ведь индекс последнего положительного числа остается в цикле while?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку нужно найти не любую, а самую длинную серию - придётся обходить весь список циклом for.

Внутри него можно запоминать индекс начала серии положительных, и когда серия кончается - найти её длину и сравнить с максимальной, запомнить индексы, если она самая длинная

После окончания цикла собрать новый список из трёх срезов.

```
import random
A = []
for i in range (15):
    A.append (random.randint (-20, 50))
print (A)
maxlen = 0
maxstart = -1
start = -1
positive = False
for i in range(len(A)+1):
    if positive:
        if i == len(A) or A[i] <= 0:
            if i - start > maxlen:
                maxlen = i - start
                maxstart = start
            positive = False
    else:
        if not positive:
            start = i
            positive = True
B = A[0:maxstart] + A[maxstart + maxlen:] + A[maxstart:maxstart + maxlen]
print(maxstart, maxlen)
print(B)

[-19, -13, 15, -6, 30, 4, -15, 36, 50, -2, 27, 26, -14, 23, -8]
4 2
[-19, -13, 15, -6, -15, 36, 50, -2, 27, 26, -14, 23, -8, 30, 4]
```

Comment: @Тимур Шакиров Что-то непонятно?

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!